# Jquery show and hide controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I know to show and hide control. I do the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (x ==1)
    {
        $("#div1").show();
        //or
        $("#div1").css("display", "block");
    }
    else
    { 
        $("#div1").hide();
        //or
        $("#div1").css("display", "none");
    }
});
```

Regardless the approach, it works. Will it hide the control completely. What I mean is if I use IE f12 tool or Chrome/firefox inspector, will I still see it.

Actually, it still shows like this

```
<div id="div1" style="display: none;">
</div
```

Can I hide that completely, so people will not change from display:none to display:block

The other way is doing it in server side.

However, I am trying to show/hide file upload control. If the user selects a particular value in drop down box, the fileupload will be shown and hidden. That can only be done using updatepanel. fileupload does not work with updatepanel. It took me a while to figure out. Then I use the jquery. That works fine. Then I found that I did not hide controls during the rendering

Any suggestions 
Thanks

Comment: remove it so it wont show anywhere

Comment: Add/Remove the element from the DOM. You need to know the parent of the element as it will be needed to add in..

Comment: If you don't want your users seeing the html <div> then create those elements dynamically from within jquery.  What's shown in Chrome Dev Tools > Elements tab (or other browser dev tools) is the document loaded in the browser's memory as it was read from source from your webserver.  Any dynamic changes via jquery will reflect here, but the html source stays the same (dynamic changes will not be saved to file when user saves the html page.)

Comment: Why not make a DIV, and inside the DIV, put the fileupload control here, then you can hide/show the div

Comment: User2012384-22, that is what I am doing, creating fileupload inside a div. I show/hide div. The other people have given me good advice. I am going to try it. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Please use .detach() instead of .remove() if you might want to re-insert the DOM later. .detach() would keep all jQuery data associated ,such as event attached, with the removed elements while .remove() cannot.

https://api.jquery.com/detach/